# Movement speed when using abilities

Tags: overwatch

Some abilities affect your movement speed when being used such as Deadeye. How much does do these abilities change your movement speed?

Comment: Relevant spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tb7xg_EmtkqgR7da6IDMcFjdEsFkefcW_78mAIRKp0w/edit#gid=1521377263

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Base movement speed is 5.5 (6 for Genji and Tracer), base crouched movement speed is 3 for all heroes. Note that Lucio speed boost gives a 30% increase and a 110% increase when amped up. Speed is measured in meters/second.

**Bastion**

- Sentry Mode: 0
- Tank Mode: 5.5

**D. Va (Mech)**

- Boosters: 12.5
- Fusion Cannons: 1.33

**Genji**

- Swift Strike: 35
- Dragonblade: 8

**Lúcio (Speed)**

- Base: 7.1
- Crouched: 3.8
- Amped Speed: 11.66

**McCree**

- Deadeye: 2

**Mercy**

- Flying: Unknown

**Pharah**

- Hover Jets:  5.5

**Reaper**

- Wraith Form: 7.1
- Death Blossom:   3

**Reinhardt**

- Barrier Field: 2.75
- Charge:  16.66

**Roadhog**

- Whole Hog:   2.5

**Soldier: 76**

- Sprint: 8.33

**Sombra**

- Thermoptic Camo: 8.8

**Widowmaker**

- Grappling Hook:  16
- Scoped   1.9

**Winston**

- Jump Pack: 20
- Primal Rage: 7.1

**Zenyatta**

- Transcendence:   11

[source](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tb7xg_EmtkqgR7da6IDMcFjdEsFkefcW_78mAIRKp0w/edit#gid=1521377263)

Comment: I think it'd be better to say "base movement speed is 5.5 except for Genji & Tracer at 6. Crouching is 3," instead of listing the base and crouched repeatedly. It's more tedious to see if all your numbers line up than it is just to check the source. And instead of raw values, say stuff like "speed-amped Lucio is more than 2× faster (than the average base)".

Comment: @NiteCyper good idea, done

Comment: You have a different base speed listed for Lucio, should probably add that to Genji and Tracer at the top. It looks like Lucio also has a higher crouch speed. Genji and Tracer still crouch at 3?

Comment: @DCShannon the different base is for when he is using his speed, i suppose I could combine it though. and yes, genji and tracer crouch walk at 3

Comment: @Dragonrage Oh, I got you. I didn't even really notice the words in the parentheses. Now that I have, I will point out that Recon Mode and Tank Mode are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @DCShannon fixed bastion's info

Comment: +1, do Lucio's speed figures also apply to his teammates in his aura? In other words, I'm Reaper and I'm standing next to a speed Lucio. How fast am I? Tracer?

Comment: What about D. Va in pilot form is her movement speed also 6?

Comment: @DCShannon speed boost gives +30% aura and amped +110% and FlamingThunder, pilot form is still 5.5

Comment: @Dragonrage The speed for Zen's Transcendence is most likely wrong. If base speed is 5.5 and his ult increases speed then it should be well over 5.5.

Comment: @dustyjuicebox, correct. I forgot they had upped his speed. fixed

Comment: Do these speeds have units (meters/second, perhaps)? Having these numbers is good to know the speeds relative to other heroes, but that doesn't really say anything about how fast they're actually travelling on the map.

Comment: @MageXy, yea its m/s. thought i had put that in there. added